# Is there a syntax to refer to the domain of a partial function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to formally represent a `Map` (in programming sense), with a partial function mapping. Lets say this partial function is $Q : S \mapsto T$, where $S$ and $T$ are discrete finite sets.

Is there any standard way to refer to the domain of $Q$ that is a subset of $S$ (since it is a partial function)? (As in getting the set of `keys` of the `Map`)

Also what is the standard way to add a new mapping? Does this make sense:
$Q' = Q \cup \{s \to t\} $ ? What about removing a mapping with key $s$?

Comment: A *map* is a *relation* i.e. a set of *ordered couples* : $\langle x, y \rangle$. Thus $Q′ = Q \cup \{ \langle s,t \rangle \}$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. What guarantees the uniqueness of the first element of the pair though with respect to the other pairs? And what is the way of referring to the set of first elements of each pair?

Comment: A relation $R$ is a [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) when, if $R(x_1)=y$ and $R(x_2)=y$, then $x_1=x_2$. The set of first elements of $R$ is $Dom(R) = \{ x \mid \exists y ( \langle x,y \rangle \in R) \}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is $Dom(R)$ standard or do I have to define it as you did before I use it?

Comment: Yes, it is the standard definition of [domain of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function).